# Получение буквы диска по его номеру

Tags: c++, winapi, файловая-система

Здравствуйте. У меня такая проблема. Есть приложение на С, которое форматирует диск, номер которого я ввожу.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Shlobj.h>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    WORD DriveNumber;
    const int SHFMT_OPT_DEFAULT = 0xFFFF;
    cout << "Please write the number of tom, which you want to formation (the value of tom number represents a letter drive starting at 0 for the A: drive, 1 for the B: drive, and so on through the alphabet): ";
    cin >> DriveNumber;

    SHFormatDrive(0, DriveNumber, SHFMT_OPT_DEFAULT, 0);

}
```

Все прекрасно, но мне хотелось бы сделать проверку, которая состояла бы в том, есть ли на компьютере том, номер которого я ввожу, если нет выдавало бы ошибку. Не знаете как это сделать?

Comment: Я бы написал вводил букву, кстати.

Comment: `RealDriveType()` - то, что нужно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужна функция [`GetLogicalDrives`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364972%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Она выдаёт битовую маску, соответствующую доступным дискам.

```
DWORD drives = GetLogicalDrives();
if (drives == 0)
{
    // ошибка? проверим GetLastError() и возможно выйдем
}
if (drives & (1 << DriveNumber) == 0)
{
    // такого диска нету
```

Не забудьте подключить `<Windows.h>` и проверить ошибку через `GetLastError()`.

Comment: а как понять if (drives & (1 << DriveNumber) == 0) ? Не совсем понятно что оно делает

Comment: Хм.. А если захочется больше 26, а то и 32 дисков?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну, столько букаф нету в английском алфавите :-(

Comment: @Alex: `(1 << DriveNumber)` получает число с битом в позиции, соответствующей `DriveNumber` (`<<` — это побитовый сдвиг). Поскольку `drives` — битовая маска, в ней каждый бит соответствует одному диску. `drives & (1 << DriveNumber)` выделяет нужный бит. Такис образом, мы смотрим, это ноль или не ноль, то есть нужный бит есть или нету.

Comment: @VladD, для консоли это не помеха: https://forum.unrealcommander.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=775

Comment: @Qwertiy: Круто, не знал. Впрочем, официальное API поддерживает максимум 32 диска в любом случае :-\